# Is it true that adding an attributive sometimes causes a change in part of speech of the main word?

Tags: существительные, наречия

Please look at the following two sentences:

1. Летом она отдыхала в санатории.
2. Этим летом она отдыхала в санатории.

What part of speech is the word "летом" in the 1st and in the 2nd sentence? It seems pretty weird, but I have a feeling that adding "этим" caused the word "летом" to change its part of speech.

зимой --> прошлой зимой; осенью --> ранней осенью...

Is there a linguistical term for this phenomenon?

Comment: In English, even adding any attributive words is not needed for a word to change from an adverb (“_I want this done **today**_”) to a noun (_“**Today** is the day we'll fix this once and for all.”_)

Comment: The former is a adverb converted from the noun лето in instrumental case (also often used as temporalis or locative in Russian) The latter is a verb without conversion. It's literally same as "Today"(noun) - "Today"(adverb) - "To this day" (a noun "day"!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What part of speech is the word "летом" in the 1st and in the 2nd sentence?

It's an adverb in the first sentence and a noun in the second sentence.

> Is there a linguistical term for this phenomenon?

This is called "[conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation))" or "null derivation".

In this particular case it would be called "null-derived adverbialization" (forming an adverb from a certain form of a noun without changing this form whatsoever)